Connecting vector of an expandable connector in Dymola and OpenModelica
I'm trying to connect a vector of connector to a vector of expandable connector. Here is the sample code to reproduce the issues. I explore 3 ways to do the connections, through blocks Adapter One to Three.

First one connects the vectors of variables, works fine under Dymola, fails under OME (AdapterOne failed with no error message)
Second one connects manually each element of each vector, works fine.
Third one connects with a loop each element of each vector, check fails under Dymola (Failed to expand connect) and OME (Error: Internal error NFSubscript.toDAE failed on unknown subscript 1).

What am I doing wrong ?
Tested with OME v1.23.1 (64bits) and Dymola 2024 refresh1 (windows 64bits)
package Test
  expandable connector Bus
  end Bus;

  connector IntegerOutput = output Integer;

  block Source
    IntegerOutput y=1;
  end Source;

  block AdapterOne
    parameter Integer numberOfItems = 2;
    Bus engineBus[numberOfItems];
    Source source[numberOfItems](each y=3);
  equation 
  connect(source.y, engineBus.value);
  end AdapterOne;

  block AdapterTwo
    parameter Integer numberOfItems = 2;
    Bus engineBus[numberOfItems];
    Source source[numberOfItems](each y=3);
  equation 
      connect(source[1].y, engineBus[1].level);
      connect(source[2].y, engineBus[2].level);
  end AdapterTwo;

  model AdapterThree
    parameter Integer numberOfItems = 2;
    Bus engineBus[numberOfItems];
    Source source[numberOfItems](each y=3);
  equation 
    for i in 1:numberOfItems loop
        connect(source[i].y, engineBus[i].level);
    end for;
  end AdapterThree;

end Test;



The code is correct (unless I missed something), and all cases will work in the next release of Dymola. A work-around for Dymola is to use the following:
block AdapterTwoAndHalf
  parameter Integer numberOfItems = 2;
  Bus engineBus[numberOfItems];
  Source source[numberOfItems](each y=3);
equation 
  connect(source[1:numberOfItems].y, engineBus[1:numberOfItems].level);
end AdapterTwoAndHalf;


The AdapterTwoAndHalf works just fine also in JModelica! But OpenModelica 1.25.0-dev reports translation error "Internal error instantiation of Test.AdapterTwoAndHalf failed with no error message".

Thanks for the hints. I will wait the next Dymola release. The difficult point is making it work on other modelica platforms, notably OpenModelica.

Thanks. Yesterday I actually contacted Adrian Pop to make him aware of the problem. He is deeply involved in the OpenModelica development over many years and also active on this site under his true name. Best would be if you make a formal issue on Github of your case and you get an issue number and a dialogue.

you're right thanks for the proposal. I will take time to submit a bug on github. In fact, I already submitted another bug request on expandable connectors, the anwer was that it needed complete rewrite to address the issue. The corrective developments are expected to take place after next release.

I am not familiar with expandable connectors, but seems to be an interesting and very useful concept. Reproduced your results in OME 1.23.1 as well as in the nightly buid 1.25.0...
Then I tried (deprecated) JModelica ver 2.14  from Modelon. Translation worked fine - in all thee examples!
Further I simulated each FMU using PyFMI for one second and could get a time series of source[].y as well as for engineBus[].level. All time series gives the value 3 all the time, of course.
With this result I expect that the Modelon commercial tool Impact would accept your code.
I have over the years mainly experience with JModelica and OpenModelica. There has been times when JModelica compilation to FMU accept Modelica code and produce the right functionality, even though OpenModelica brings translation errors. And when you look up the details I have several times found that the OpenModelica complaints has been correct towards the Modelica standard, but not always. If this is the case also in your examples I do not know.
Perhaps interesting to run Dymola in a "less pedantic mode" and see if that helps?

Thanks for these feedbacks, I appreciate. My experience so far with the various Modelica tools I'm using, is, they all have various compliance levels with the Modelica Standard. If for basic usage of the language, cross-platform compliancy is ok, when it comes to advanced usage, it does not work and makes it difficult to build Modelica code that is running fine for under all Modelica platform. I dream of an official set of up-to-date open-source Modelica language test-cases that all implementations should pass.

I checked with Modelon support and they confirm their software Impact can handle expandable connectors well. Modelon actually use these kind of connectors in some of their libraries for years.
